# How do you run a scheme program in the terminal of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scheme

I have searched and I really can't seem to find this really basic question. I am new to mit-scheme and essentially I want to recreate hello world but instead of doing it through the prompt, I want to have a scheme file that contains the following code:

```
 (define hello-world
 (lambda ()
     (begin
        (write 'Hello-World)
        (newline)
        (hello-world))))
```

The problem is I am missing the simplest questions: What is the file extension for a scheme file? How do I run that file through scheme?

I have tried `.ss` and `.scm` but every time I try `scheme hello-world.scm` it says:

```
;Warning: Invalid keyword: "hello-world.scm"

;Warning: Unhandled command line options: ("hello-world.scm")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your issue isn't the file extension, it's just that MIT Scheme prints an error if invoked as `scheme hello-world.scm`, since it's supposed to be invoked as

```
scheme --load hello-world.scm
```

Also, note that you are using a left-quote character `‘` rather than the actual quote character `'`.  If you look closely you can see the difference.

Comment: Ah yes I see that, that would cause problems thank you. I changed it but I'm still getting the ;Warning: Invalid keyword: "hello-world.scm"
;Warning: Unhandled command line options: ("hello-world.scm") when I try this command line: scheme hello-world.scm

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to scheme and couldn't find that dang --load anywhere!

Comment: @WarGravy You're welcome!  In general, if you have a command which you think you might be invoking incorrectly, try `man <command>`, `help <command>`, or `<command> --help`.  Often you'll find usage information in one of those spots.

Answer (score 11):

Start the scheme interpreter in the same directory as your file. Once you are in the interpreter of mit-scheme, you can always use the following procedure which is built into scheme:

```
(load "file-name.extension")
```

This will load the file into scheme.
I hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Visual Studio Code** as an editor, you may want to use the "Code Runner extension" 
make sure it's installed from the vs code marketplace 
then enter `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` and past the following:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "scheme": "(exit); racket -i -e '(enter! \"$fileName\")'",
    },
```

You will be able to run directly your file by clicking the `Run Code` icon or by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+N`

**NB:** putting `#lang racket` in the top of your file is necessary